# Class structure for command-line interface

Tags: c#, delegates, command, command-line-interface

I am developing a simple command-line interface in C#. Currently it parses the user's input and runs down a long chain of if-then-else statements to execute the various commands the user can type. Some examples:

- making directories
- deleting directories recursively
- entering directories
- listing directories
- entering a text editor or some other tools I'm writing for it like an text-based UI for an ASM-variant I made along with an interpreter or some math tools or games like a gravity simulator or conway's game of life
- saving the state of everything
- a help function
- renaming a file
- deleting a file

The if-then chain was only to get things working. I want to approach the way commands are represented in the interface in a better way.

My first thought is to have a `Class Command` with some properties like:

- the summary entry for the command that would be listed when the user types `help`
- the more specific information when the user would type help `help 'specific
  command'`
- number of arguments
- a delegate for the function to be called when the command is executed

Since this is only my first thought and I'm relatively new to this, I was wondering what a better way might be.

Comment: I wrote a reusable command line interface library that met my specific needs on a couple of projects. Maybe it will offer you some additional ideas to think about on your journey. https://github.com/mariocatch/YACL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch case might be better than if..else in this scenario like:

```
switch (command)
{
    case "copy":
        // Copy
        break;
    case "create":
        // Create;
        break;
}
```

For commands, command pattern is the best way to implement the interface, few references to start with command design pattern:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Design-Patterns-Command-1962d567
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/command.aspx

You can also refer sample implementation of command line utilities online, to find out how to parse the command line arguments, for example:
http://crmcommandline.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the lateness of my reply. Marked as best